# Error using hoistNonReactStatics, withApollo, withContext and React-Navigation

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-navigation

I am trying to run a graphql query (and store the response in my context). But, when I do that, my react-navigation header is not rendering. I researched on the internet and understand we can use hoistNonReactStatics to preserve the statics.

I am unable to get the code to work. What I have done so far is given below, I am unable to run my graphql query.

How should I structure my code in order for it to work? Thanks :)

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
render() {
   return ...
}

hoistNonReactStatics(
  HomeScreen,
  compose(
    withContext,
    withApollo
  )(HomeScreen)
);

export default HomeScreen;
```